# JAVA - remove and copy a ChangeListener from a JSlider

Tags: java, jslider, changelistener

I'm having trouble with a Slider for a Volumecontrol.

Atm I use FloatControl to handle the MasterVolume of an Audioclip, bad for me I need a new ChangeListener for every new AudioClip - so i tried this:

```
JSlider slider_Vol // the Object i use the whole time
JSlider tempSlider // a temporary used Slider i create in an other function

if (slider_Vol.getChangeListeners() != null)            
  slider_Vol.removeChangeListener(slider_Vol.getChangeListeners()[0]); //Array[0] correct position?

slider_Vol.addChangeListener(tempSlider.getChangeListeners()[0]);
```

it seems like my `If` dont work, because there is allready an exceptions for the remove command when the program starts and no changelistener was created.

Any ideas?

Comment: have you tried to put it in `try catch`?

Comment: well, I "catched" the exception, but still dont know why and what to do now - its still dont work

Comment: Why don't you just maintain a reference to the instance of the listener?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try changing the statement to:

```
ChangeListener listener;
if (!slider_Vol.getChangeListeners().length == 0){
    listener = slider_Vol.getChangeListeners()[0]
    slider_Vol.removeChangeListener(slider_Vol.getChangeListeners()[0]);
} else {
    listener = new ChangeListener[your code];
}
slider_Vol.addChangeListener(listener);
```

Comment: great, this solved the Problem with the if (....length !=0)
any idea how the do a bether copy, because the change listener added after this is never called if i run the project

Comment: it somehow dont copy the right ChangeListener, dont realy know why....

is "slider.getChangeListerners()[0]" realy the rigth call for this?

Comment: I don't know, not enough of your code is shown. If you are having problems with arrays you should probably try some basic Java tutorials first.